# Animating CALayers in background with setNeedsDisplay

Tags: ios

I am porting my library from Andriod to IOS and I have made a great deal of progress and learned a little about Objective C in the process. I say a little, because there is a lot to learn. The Android library creates a surfaceView  and does animation by drawing the images directly to the surfaceView; in Objective C, I am using a UIView with CALayers.

In the UIView I am dynamically adding CALayers loaded with Sprite Sheet images and then moving the CALayers around in the UIView while roating through the Sprite image in the CALayer by moving the contentsRect of the CALayer.

This all works perfectly in a background thread in Android and does not interfere with the host application. In Objective C, I am trying to run it in the background as well using either performSelectorInBackground or the new Grand Central Dispatch. Both seem to work in the background fine, loading images into the CALayers and then I hit the snag: the CALayers are not displaying.

I know the CALayers are there, because when I pause the app in the simulator by clicking on the middle hardware button and then click again to display it the CALayers are there looking great – but static.

Having read posts for days and trying various ways of setting NeedsDisplay and NeedsLayout on the UIView and the individual CALayers, I have given up and I am asking for your help.

So, please take a look at the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.  I am also having problems setting the frame of my CALayers. When I try to set them with [self setFrame: CGRectMake(0,0,spWidth, spHeight)] – both NSIntegers; I get an error saying Sending CGRect to parameter of incompatible type NSInteger. I know this is probably a rookie mistake.

Here are the relevant sections of my code. I will post more, but I am hoping that my error is in the run method.

In my custom UIView

```
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,dw,dh)])){

    (initialization and defining variables)

    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, dw, dh);
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,dw,dh);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    MainDrawLayer  = [[CALayer layer]retain];
    MainDrawLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, dw, dh); //dw=320 dh=50.
    MainDrawLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,dw,dh);

    [self.layer addSublayer:MainDrawLayer] ;
    }
    return self;
```

All of the action is triggered in the run method below which I call from the ViewController.

```
    - (void) run {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{

    PGM = [[[GadsMonitor alloc] init:   @"http://www.javelin21.com/servlets/theloader" :_displaySizeW :_displaySizeH]autorelease];

   while(!PGM.adsdone){
   [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
    NSLog(@"The value of adsdone is %@\n", (PGM.adsdone ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
   }

   NSLog(@"Into processComponent Number in PGM.PGVarray %d ", PGM.PGVarray.count);

   GVarray = [PGM.PGVarray mutableCopy];
   NSLog(@"Into RUN after copy  GVArray %d ", GVarray.count);


   Gad * readyGad = (Gad *) [GVarray objectAtIndex:0];
   if (readyGad != nil)
   [readyGad getImages];

   NSLog(@"The value of the bool is %@\n", (readyGad.gdone ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

  while (!readyGad.gdone) {
     [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];
     [readyGad checkImages];
    NSLog(@"The value of the readyGad.gdone is %@\n", (readyGad.gdone ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
    }
    rstop = NO;


   while (!rstop) {
    NSLog(@"The value of rstop in while is %@\n", (rstop ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    [self rotateGames];

    stop = NO;

   while (!stop) {
        [self gameAction];
        [self paint];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self setNeedsLayout]; //I have also tried self.layer
      [self  setNeedsDisplay]; //I have also tried self.layer
        });

        //These are various timers for CALayer action
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:stime];
        rtime = (rtime +runGad.gslp);
        ltime += runGad.gslp;
        jtime += runGad.gslp;
        vtime += runGad.gslp;
        ftime += runGad.gslp;
        ttime += runGad.gslp;
        Stime += runGad.gslp;

        NSLog(@"After Thread Sleep rtime + gslp %f ", rtime);

        if ((runTime += runGad.gslp) >= runGad.grun) {
            stop = YES;
        }
    }

   stop = NO;
  }
  });
```

}

I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS any UI updating code must be performed in the main thread.  You cannot use GCD (unless its running on the mainQueue) or performSelectorInBackground to update the UI.

You can update your data and do IO on background threads, but when you have the data loaded and you want to display it you must switch back to the main thread.

Trying to do otherwise will sometimes work, sometimes not, or crash your app.

The main thread owns UI updates in iOS.

Also when it comes to doing the work on the main thread you have a few options, you can queue a block up with performSelectorOnMainThread

or you can send a block to the main thread GCD queue, sometimes you may need to play with dispatch_async vs dispatch_sync on the main thread if you use GCD they dont both work in every situation.  performSelectorInMainthread seems to be more reliable than GCDs main thread queue.

ymmv

Comment: ymmv - thank you for your comment. I have tried performSelectorOnMainThread, but it did not work.

Comment: ymmv - Sorry, I misread your post. I will try performSelectorOnMainThread. I am calling performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:false). Is this the correct way - how does it know to setNeedsDisplay on my UIVIew?

Comment: setNeedsDisplay is not really the issue, any UI code has to be in the main thread setting the frame size, setting an image anything.  setNeedsDisplay is not really needed in most situations.  You cannot use the global queue for this. or a background thread.

Comment: ymmv - performSelectorOnMain did not work. I tried removing performSelectorInBackground and the screen went black and did not show the white background view.

Comment: I have change my layer classes to NSObjects and just create a CALayer on init. I think this will help, as I am only doing calculating now and doing the UI in the main thread.  But now the layers are not being added to my UIView. When I NSLog[self.layer.sublayers count]); it is zero. I am adding the layers this way [self.layer addSublayer:ags.t_layer]; and creating layers in my NSObject classes this way: t_layer = [[CALayer alloc] init]. I am adding the image this way, but it was working before - t_layer.contents = (id) ppImage.CGImage; (however, not on main thread)